# - There is no report design object available. in birt web viewer

Tags: eclipse

org.eclipse.birt.report.exception.ViewerException: There is no report design object available.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.ViewerAttributeBean.__init(ViewerAttributeBean.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BaseAttributeBean.init(BaseAttributeBean.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.ViewerAttributeBean.(ViewerAttributeBean.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BirtContext.__init(BirtContext.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BaseContext.(BaseContext.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BirtContext.(BirtContext.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.__getContext(ViewerServlet.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doGet(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:151)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

This is the error iam facing problem from 2 days.. While i am using BIRT viewer 3.7.1 and the report.rptdesign have developed Eclipse Luna birt. 
cloud you please give the reply..
Thanks in advance

Comment: check out this answer
[i hope it will solve your problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910616/there-is-no-report-design-object-available-in-birt-web-viewer/27224112#27224112

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure Are you Viewing your Report in Tomcat Birt Viewer Web Application????

Is It So then try to Download `org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar` file from apache website and paste the jar file to `C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\BIRT\WEB-INF\lib` folder
and Working Fine For Me