# There is no report design object available.in BIRT web viewer

Tags: php, birt

I can See the BIRT report Through Default Birt Directory

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/BIRT/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign
```

But i can't run BIRT report like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/BIRT/frameset?__report=C:/xampp/htdocs/project/test.rptdesign


ERROR:  + There is no report design object available.
```

Is there any Solution??

**Sorry my question is directed to wrong way**

If i upload my project to Web hosting server is there any configuration needed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some times it happen in birt report when we run it in browser or pdf doc etc for testing purpose in report dialogue while creating a birt report its version changes automatically and due to this reason it generate this exception that There is no report design object available

[image]

you can update your lib/jar files or can also change your report version as i have done in the above fig.

Answer (score 0):

__report variable looks for reports deployed under folder which is configured with variable inside web.xml -> BIRT_VIEWER_DOCUMENT_FOLDER

```
<!--
    Temporary document files directory. Defaults to ${birt home}/documents
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>BIRT_VIEWER_DOCUMENT_FOLDER</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you really need other location for your Birt reports you can play around with Windows folder linking or something similar to this if you use other OS.

Comment: Could you please tell me How to link with my project folder `C:/xampp/htdocs/project`???.....Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't know that, ask another question, pleanty of people will tell you that inn a sec. I need to digg it out :)

Comment: I'm curious, **why** do you need to place reports on other location?